# How to use 'or' along with 'and' operation in mongodb using its java driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

```
db.mycol.find(
    {
        "likes": { $gt: 10 }, 
        $or: [
            {"by": "tutorials point"},
            {"title": "MongoDB Overview"}
        ]
    }).pretty()
```

what would be its equivalent java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
BasicDBObject gtQuery = new BasicDBObject();
gtQuery.put("likes", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 10))

BasicDBObject q1 = new BasicDBObject("by", "tutorials point");  
BasicDBObject q2 = new BasicDBObject("title", "MongoDB Overview");    
BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
or.add(q1);
or.add(q2);
BasicDBObject orQuery = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);

List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
obj.add(gtQuery);
obj.add(orQuery );    

BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
andQuery.put("$and", obj);

System.out.println(andQuery.toString());

DBCursor cursor = mycol.find(andQuery);
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```